# How can I store each random sample with different name in R, using seed()?

Tags: r, random

I am trying to figure out which random sample will offer me a better accuracy against the training and testing data sets for the following data set:
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Skin+Segmentation

Here is the code what I have written till now:

```
# Code for Skin/Non-Skin Data using Naive Bayes Classifier

require(e1071)   #This package holds the Naive Bayes Classifier
require(caTools) #Loading this package for sampling or to split the data set
require(psych)
require(magrittr) #For %>%
require(dplyr)    #For bind and head

set.seed(123)    #set seed to ensure you always have same random numbers generated

#Dataset after taking 10% from the mother dataset

samples = sample.split(Data_Skin_Segmentation$Class,SplitRatio = 1/10)
newdata = subset(Data_Skin_Segmentation, samples== TRUE)
newdata$Class=as.factor(newdata$Class)

#part splits the data in the ratio mentioned in SplitRatio. 
#After splitting marks these rows as logical TRUE and the the remaining are marked as logical FALSE
part = sample.split(newdata$Class,SplitRatio = 0.4)

#creates a training dataset named train_set with rows which are marked as TRUE
train_set = subset(newdata, part==TRUE)

#creates a testing dataset named test_set with rows which are marked as FALSE
test_set = subset(newdata, part==FALSE)

View(train_set)  #View the training data set
View(test_set)   #View the testing data set

#This is valid only for the variable with two class classification problem

levels(train_set$Class)

model = naiveBayes(Class~., data = train_set)
class(model)

train_set %>%
    summarise(mean(B),sd(B))

pred = predict(model, train_set, type = 'raw')
head(cbind(pred,train_set))

#Confusion matrix - train data
p1= predict(model,train_set)
(tab1=table(p1,train_set$Class))
misclassification1 = 1- sum(diag(tab1)) / sum(tab1)

#Confusion matrix - test data
p2= predict(model,test_set)
(tab2=table(p2,test_set$Class))
misclassification2 = 1- sum(diag(tab2)) / sum(tab2)

#Confusion matrix- test data - Whole Set
p3= predict(model,Data_Skin_Segmentation)
(tab3=table(p3,Data_Skin_Segmentation$Class))
misclassification3 = 1- sum(diag(tab3)) / sum(tab3)
```

You can see in the code, "set.seed(123)" has been used to get the exact random numbers at each run.
But now, I want to get random samples and store each randomly(probably different) generated samples with different names, e.g., train1, test1 (for the first run), train2, test2 ( for the second run) and so on. Which will be further used in the naive bayes model.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to clarify your problem description and add some minimal, verfiable, complete code. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where is the `seed()` function from? Are you using a package that overrides the normal `set.seed()`? What have you tried? And why are you doing this? (It seems like it would serve no useful purpose.)

Comment: As an aside I don't think choosing your "random" sample so that you get the best results possible qualifies as "random" :)

Comment: Thank you all, for the suggestions and responses . Yes, I am new to Stackoverflow and programming in R at the same time, so pardon my mistakes and any further suggestions are heartily welcome:)

I have edited the question body and tried to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The following function will loop through 1 to `n`, each time generating samples using a different seed and store them into a matrix `x`:

```
someseed <- function(n, samplesize){
    x <- matrix(ncol = samplesize+1, nrow=n)
    for(i in 1:n){
        set.seed(i)
        x[i,] <- c(i, runif(samplesize))
    }
    return(x)
}
```

10 random samples (size of 4) generated from Seed 1 to 10:

```
someseed(10, 4)

      [,1]      [,2]        [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
 [1,]    1 0.2655087 0.372123900 0.5728534 0.90820779
 [2,]    2 0.1848823 0.702374036 0.5733263 0.16805192
 [3,]    3 0.1680415 0.807516399 0.3849424 0.32773432
 [4,]    4 0.5858003 0.008945796 0.2937396 0.27737496
 [5,]    5 0.2002145 0.685218596 0.9168758 0.28439946
 [6,]    6 0.6062683 0.937641973 0.2643521 0.38009392
 [7,]    7 0.9889093 0.397745453 0.1156978 0.06974868
 [8,]    8 0.4662952 0.207823317 0.7996580 0.65187132
 [9,]    9 0.2216014 0.024233910 0.2071190 0.21573355
[10,]   10 0.5074782 0.306768506 0.4269077 0.69310208
```

The first column correspond to the seed number, and the remaining are the "random sample" generated with that seed. You can then loop through your `predict()` function on the matrix `x` and print an accuracy score for each sample you generated.

---

**Important Advice**

The above is what you can do to achieve what you asked for, but like others have stated in the comment this may actually be counter-productive to your goal. Specifically, the reason you have a test set (or validation set) is to **obtain an unbiased estimate of your model's performance on unseen data**. When you're trying to find a seed number that generate the best test accuracy, this already introduce bias to your estimate, and your "test accuracy" is at best an optimistic estimation of how it would perform in the real world, against unseen data.

I would caution against the use of it - there may be genuine reason why you would want to do this (looping through different sets of seed and each time logging the accuracy), but I am not convinced in this case that this serves in your best interest.

---